# i am trying to create foreign key constraint in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5.8

I can't create a foreign table key:

```
$table->increments('rt_id');
$table->integer('issued_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('issued_id')->references('issue_id')->on('book_issues');            
$table->integer('book_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('book_details');
```

I also tried this:

```
$table->bigIncrements('rt_id'); 
$table->unsignedBigInteger('issued_id');  
$table->foreign('issued_id')->references('issue_id')->on('book_issues');                
$table->unsignedBigInteger('book_id');
$table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('book_details');
```

Comment: so, what is the error you're having exactly?

Comment: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_library`.`#sql-2c4c_3` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")        ---- this is what the error i am getting.

Comment: In updated the a answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rechecked all the fields and the datatype, i observed that i used increments for primary key and in foreign key i had taken integer('book_id')->unsigned()
And while migrating, i already had the primary table migrated so, i used php artisan migrate:fresh command then this time, it is migrating the foreign table time so, i'm getting the error.
 before my foreign key table is been placed first and then the primary key table is placed at last.
So, i changed my model name and replaced according to key constraints as primary table should be stored first in migration folder even sometimes while migrating it doesn't migrates in sequences in ur folder.
So, i used php artisan migrate:fresh
This command is migrating all tables in sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Looking both of your tables I figured it out that in order to get successful foriegn key... **the referenced and referencing fields must have exactly the same data type and options** .

So in your case you should remove `unsignedBigInteger`  and `unsigned` just use `integer` like this:

`$table->integer('issued_id')`

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: i am trying to make foreign key for book_id field and in my primary table i used id field

Comment: this is my primary table:                                    
   Schema::create('book_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->String('book_name');
      $table->String('book_author');
      $table->String('book_publisher');
      $table->String('book_supplier');
      $table->String('book_dept');
      $table->String('book_image');
      $table->String('book_price');
      $table->String('book_edition');
      $table->String('book_status');
      $table->String('book_stock');
      $table->timestamps();
      });

Comment: still i am getting the same error :                               Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_library`.`#sql-2c4c_24` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `book_issues` add constraint `book_issues_book_id_foreign` foreign key (`book_id`) references `book_details` (`id`))